# Python code to extract the max pain value of a SBIN stock from https://www.niftytrader.in/stock-options-chart/sbin not working - what am I missing?

Tags: python-3.x

I want python code to scrape max pain value of a SBIN Stock from url https://www.niftytrader.in/stock-options-chart/sbin

My code is ..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.niftytrader.in/stock-options-chart/sbin"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

max_pain_element = soup.find("span", class_="fs-3 label-color-3")

if max_pain_element:
    # Extract the Max Pain value
    max_pain = max_pain_element.text.strip()
    print("Max Pain:", max_pain)
else:
    print("Max Pain value not found on the webpage.")
```

But, i am getting output as "Max Pain value not found on the webpage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. To get all data into a dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = 'https://h9cg992bof.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/webapi/symbol/psymbol-list'

data =requests.get(api_url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['resultData'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    symbol_name  today_close  prev_close  max_pain  lot_size
0      AARTIIND       494.70      495.65     500.0     850.0
1           ABB      3894.75     3897.50    3700.0     250.0
2    ABBOTINDIA     20898.45    20970.55   21000.0      40.0
3     ABCAPITAL       163.90      164.80     165.0    5400.0
4         ABFRL       190.85      193.70     200.0    2600.0
5           ACC      1729.05     1712.45    1760.0     250.0
6      ADANIENT      1956.05     1890.00    1900.0     250.0
7    ADANIPORTS       688.10      664.95     690.0     625.0
8         ALKEM      3302.10     3326.30    3400.0     200.0

...
```

---

To get only `SBIN` value:

```py
print(df[df.symbol_name == 'SBIN'].iloc[0]['max_pain'])
```

Prints:

```
580.0
```