# Scrapping max pain value from nifty trader website

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.niftytrader.in/nse-option-chain/tcs"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Create BeautifulSoup object and parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")



# Find the <span> element within the <div>
span_element = soup.find('span', class_="label-color-4 fs-3 fw-normal")

# Extract the value of the <span> tag
span_value = span_element.text

# Print the extracted value
print(span_value)
```

The desired put is non- zero value..but the output is shown as 0.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76296844/10035985